# Expiring cookies and redirect

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I'm using an ashx file to terminate a user session and redirect to the main page. The redirecting does not work as well as the routine to expire cookies. 
I tried HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect ("index.aspx", false) but did not work either. What better way? Thank you.

My code:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["user"];
    if (cookie != null)
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["user"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30);
    cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["admin"];
    if (cookie != null)
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["admin"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("index.aspx", false);      
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this Generic Handler (.ashx)? Are you calling through ajax?

Comment: Yes, through a javascript routine that contains ajax command to call the logout.ashx.

logout function ()
{
     $ .ajax ({
         url: "logout.ashx"
         contentType: "application / json; charset = utf-8"
         dataType: "html"
     })
}

Comment: I see a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866856/trying-to-redirect-from-an-ashx-page-to-an-aspx-page

Answer (score 0):

If your handler returns a 302 result the ajax call won't automatically redirect the user, it will return the content of the page redirected to.

You should have the handler expire the cookie and return true if there are no exceptions, otherwise return false. In the success callback of the ajax call redirect the user to the next page via javascript if the result is true. If false, show them some kind of error message.

For the cookie expiration you have to get the cookie from the request, set the expiry time to a time in the past (like you are doing currently) but the one thing are not doing is adding the cookie back to the response.